# Responding with "*ok*" to a json callback in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now. I am trying to interface with the Blockchain API using rails. The API notifies my app of a specific event by means of a callback and I have to answer to this callback by responding `“*ok*”`. I am having a hard time creating a valid JSON response that consists only of `“*ok*”`. I can send an empty string `format.json { render :json => {} }` or something like `format.json { render :json => {:ok => “*ok*”} }` but can’t figure out how to send just the required `“*ok*”`.

http://blockchain.info/api/api_receive

Expected Response
In order to acknowledge successful processing of the callback the server should respond with the text "*ok*". If the server responds with anything else the callback will be resent again every new block (approximately every 10 minutes) up to 1000 times (1 week).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"*ok*"
```

This is invalid JSON. If you need to respond with plaintext, don't send a JSON response.

```
format.text { render text: “*ok*” }
```

or if the server isn't making a `text/plaintext` `GET` request, just respond without a `respond_to` block.

```
render text: "*ok*" and return
```

Comment: Thank you! For future reference, your second option is the correct one (no respond_to block and render text: "*ok*" and return)